# Monitoring number of mysql databases with Nagios

Tags: mysql, nagios

I would like to monitor the number of MySQL databases with Nagios. I've installed the official Nagios plugins.

I'm using 'check_mysql_query':

```
./check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.10 -c check_mysql_query
```

Nagios agent:

```
command[check_mysql_query]=/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_mysql_query -d mysql -q "select count(*) from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name not in ('mysql','information_schema');" -w 100 -c 150
```

I had to add client credentials to 'my.cnf' file.

Questions:

1. Is there any better/secure solution for this?
2. What's the minimum MySQL required privileges to run this command:

`select count(*) from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name not in ('mysql','information_schema');`

Comment: Depending on the version and configuration you're running you may also want to exclude performance_schema from the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could remove the where clause and subtract 2 to count(*): `COUNT(*)-2`.
2. You need SELECT privileges to do a SELECT.